# "Contract Too Large", not able to deploy contract on rococo

Tags: ink, smart-contract

I am deploying my contract on the rococo network and my contract wasm build size is 137K

```
Original wasm size: 188.1K, Optimized: 137.0K
```

Can you help on how to reduce the code size or any other possible way to resolve this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build contract with release flag:

```
cargo contract build --release
```

Comment: What is the upper limit for the contract wasm build?

Comment: Depends on the network. In shiden it's 128kb
https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar/blob/4017adef515772f84aa97320cd7f38dc9be2fdb7/runtime/shiden/src/lib.rs#L632

Comment: how to deploy on astar ?

Comment: You can deploy with contract-UI https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/?rpc=wss://rpc.astar.network